# get record from record range mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql

i have record on table 'badge';

```
  idbadge,namebadge,point;
   1,newbie,1000;
   2,novice,2000;
```

my question is: I want get record with value `point` in msyql query. example:

```
select * from badge where point bla bla '350'.
```

update
i try

```
"SELECT * FROM badge WHERE point > 350;"
```

but show two record

```
1,newbie,1000;
2,novice,2000;
```

i want 1 record mysql like

```
1,newbie,1000;
```

i try

```
select * from badge where point = 350;
```

and the answer is zero

im sorry for my bad english

Comment: I can't understand what you want. 350 is just one number, it's not a range.

Comment: tried: point=350 (so replace bla bla with =)?

Comment: yeah,i mean i want get record with value 350.example if i have value 350 it will show newbie record.

Comment: Order by point Limit 1

Answer (score 0):

If point field in table contains 350 then answer would be

`SELECT * FROM badge WHERE point=350;`

Answer (score 0):

This will return all records with a point value of 350 change the number to whatever you're looking for:

> SELECT * FROM badge
>   WHERE point = 350;

If you're trying to insert instead use this:

> INSERT INTO badge (idbadge,namebadge,point)
>   values (1,'newbie',1000),
>   (2,'novice',2000),
>   (3,'adept',3000);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `badge` where point > 1350 order by point asc limit 1
```

so this is query answer my question.and show 1 record
thanks all answer